# Why is there a difference in the popup dialog from .gvimrc and command line?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, gvimrc

I am using gVim's `confirm()` function to pop a dialog waiting for the user to click a button. However, there seems to be a difference in the appearance of the dialog when called from `.gvimrc`:

Using the command: `:let MyTestV = confirm("IN MY_GVIMRC")` generates the following dialog:

[image]

When this line (sans the `:`) is added in a `.gvimrc` (and the `.vimrc` as well) file, the following appears when a new gVim is opened:

[image]

Note that the dialog appears before the actual gVim window appears on the screen.

1) Why is there a difference in the appearance of the two dialogs?

2) Where can I put the command so that the dialog appears as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a variant of the typical "race condition" class of bugs.  Start a non-GUI version of Vim and run your `confirm()` command and you'll see where the extra text comes from.  Basically, Vim is putting the non-GUI `confirm()` text into the GUI popup because, at the time of your `.vimrc` being run the GUI isn't actually available yet.

I suggest you email `bugs` at `vim.org` (address slightly obfuscated to slow down spambots) with a report about this.  You could even link to this SuperUser question.

***Edit:*** This problem is even worse than I suspected.  I decided to see if I could reproduce it and I put this command in my `.vimrc`:

```
echo confirm('test')
```

And I got the same result you did, but *with* an extra line added consisting of `1` which is the return value of the confirm() function.  Something is definitely wrong here.

***Edit Two:*** If delaying your `confirm()` dialog is not a problem you could do this instead:

```
autocmd VimEnter * let MyTestV = confirm("IN MY_GVIMRC")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Putting this on the startup file did not mean to be something permanent, just me playing with the startup files and the newly discovered confirm() function. I was just surprised to see this behaviour. Your solution on Edit Two makes sense (and was confirmed by @IngoKarkat).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running into undefined behavior; functions that interact with the user are not supposed to be executed from `~/.vimrc`, as the GUI hasn't been properly initialized yet. `:help input()` contains a warning:

> NOTE: This function must not be used in a startup file, for
>     the versions that only run in GUI mode (e.g., the Win32 GUI).

If you need to query something from the user immediately after startup, use `:autocmd VimEnter` to trigger it.

Comment: Thanks. You're probably right. Your solution was also suggested by @Heptite. I just wonder if this should be reported as a bug, as he suggested (probably not, as this is expected assuming the GUI really get restarted after the init scripts).

Comment: A reply to a bug report by Braam Moolenaar confirms that this is an expected behaviour.